# Manually setting the redirectattributes object

Tags: spring-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a POST controller method (say updateRow) that has RedirectAttributes as a parameter, since I am doing a POST to GET redirection after the method is executed. In the redirect GET method, I am accessing the flash attributes using RequestContextUtils.getInputFlashMap(). This works fine.

However, there is a scenario where I need to invoke this POST controller method from within another method. The idea is to pass a RedirectAttributes object that can act as the flash attribute carrier inside the "updateRow" method.

I tried using a new RedirectAttributesModelMap object, which helps in the successful execution of the "updateRow" method, but in the POST-to-GET method, the flash attributes are not available.

Is there a way I can manually define this RedirectAttributesModelMap object and bind it to the request/session?

Comment: `However, there is a scenario where I need to invoke this POST controller method from within another method.` Go into more detail about this. Also, consider refactoring it. Handler methods are endpoints for your clients. You shouldn't be invoking them internally.

Comment: There is an update functionality for each row. In a scenario where there is a bind exception for row 1, and the update button is clicked for row 2, I need to suppress the bind exception for row 1, and still process the "updateRow" method for row 2 from my exception handler method.